# Visual Code Studio with C/C++ extension: How to disable warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, zephyr-rtos

I'm working with Zephyr OS in the Visual Code Studio IDE.

Zephyr uses a lot of Macros but the C/C++ extension does not like that and throws Warnings.

One example of a warning you can see here on the screenshot "The function call is not allowed in a constant expression. C/C++(59)"
[image]

Do you probably now where I can add that warning to a kind of ignore/suppress list?

Many thanks!

Comment: the language server follows the macro and still determines it is a function call, expand the macros yourself and see if it does finish on a function